# org.JSON.JSONException : No value for weather

Tags: android, json

I have written a program to display json weather data but , i am receiving response in my logcat but my listview is not displaying , it says org.JSOn.JSONException : No value for weather

URL : http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Mumbai&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lv;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = 
       "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?
        q=Mumbai&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7";

// JSON Node names
static final String TAG_LIST = "list";
static final String TAG_DATE = "dt";
static final String TAG_TEMP = "temp";
static final String TAG_DAY = "day";
static final String TAG_NIGHT = "night";
static final String TAG_MIN = "min";
static final String TAG_MAX = "max";
static final String TAG_MORN = "morn";
static final String TAG_EVE = "eve";
static final String TAG_PRESSURE = "pressure";
static final String TAG_HUMIDITY = "humidity";
static final String TAG_WEATHER = "weather";
static final String TAG_MAIN = "main";
static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
static final String TAG_ICON = "icon";

JSONArray list = null;

JSONArray weatherList = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> weatherArrayList;

ProgressDialog pDialog;

ListViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listForecast);
    weatherArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // ForecastAdapter adapter = new ForecastAdapter(getBaseContext(),
    // forecastArray);
    // lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetWeatherDetails().execute();
}

class GetWeatherDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                list = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_LIST);
                for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = list.getJSONObject(i);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    JSONObject temp = c.getJSONObject(TAG_TEMP);
                    String day = temp.getString(TAG_DAY);
                    String night = temp.getString(TAG_NIGHT);
                    String min = temp.getString(TAG_MIN);
                    String max = temp.getString(TAG_MAX);
                    String morn = temp.getString(TAG_MORN);
                    String eve = temp.getString(TAG_EVE);
                    String pressure = c.getString(TAG_PRESSURE);
                    String humidity = c.getString(TAG_HUMIDITY);
                    weatherList = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_WEATHER);
                    for (int j = 0; j < weatherList.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject d = weatherList.getJSONObject(j);
                        String main = d.getString(TAG_MAIN);
                        String desc = d.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                        String icon = d.getString(TAG_ICON);
                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> weatherMap = new 
                        HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_DAY, day);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_NIGHT, night);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_MIN, min);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_MAX, max);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_MORN, morn);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_EVE, eve);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_PRESSURE, pressure);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_HUMIDITY, humidity);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_MAIN, main);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, desc);
                        weatherMap.put(TAG_ICON, icon);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        weatherArrayList.add(weatherMap);
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, weatherArrayList);
        // Set the adapter to the ListView
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Logcat :

```
05-21 12:39:12.174: 
D/Response:(17460): > {"cod":"200","message":0.0092,"city":{"id":1275339,"name":"Mumbai","coord":{"lon":72.847939,"lat":19.01441},"country":"IN","population":0,"sys":{"population":0}},"cnt":7,"list":[{"dt":1432191600,"temp":{"day":33.16,"min":24.81,"max":35.41,"night":24.81,"eve":34.14,"morn":33.16},"pressure":1006.17,"humidity":63,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":2.18,"deg":266,"clouds":0},{"dt":1432278000,"temp":{"day":32.81,"min":25.66,"max":35.27,"night":25.66,"eve":33.91,"morn":26.1},"pressure":1006.21,"humidity":66,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":2.08,"deg":274,"clouds":0},{"dt":1432364400,"temp":{"day":34.16,"min":25.66,"max":35.6,"night":25.66,"eve":34.1,"morn":27.03},"pressure":1005.64,"humidity":59,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":3.52,"deg":288,"clouds":0},{"dt":1432450800,"temp":{"day":34.63,"min":25.52,"max":35.72,"night":25.52,"eve":34.3,"morn":26.46},"pressure":1006.31,"humidity":55,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":3.67,"deg":280,"clouds":0},{"dt":1432537200,"temp":{"day":33.57,"min":24.25,"max":33.57,"night":27.11,"eve":33.03,"morn":24.25},"pressure":1003.67,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":3.48,"deg":322,"clouds":0},{"dt":1432623600,"temp":{"day":33.56,"min":24.81,"max":33.56,"night":27.5,"eve":33.35,"morn":24.81},"pressure":1004.19,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":3.32,"deg":334,"clouds":0},{"dt":1432710000,"temp":{"day":34.36,"min":25.34,"max":34.36,"night":28.31,"eve":33.89,"morn":25.34},"pressure":1004.14,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"speed":4.05,"deg":331,"clouds":0}]}

05-21 12:39:12.244: W/System.err(17460): org.json.JSONException: No value for weather
05-21 12:39:12.259: W/System.err(17460):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
05-21 12:39:12.259: W/System.err(17460):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
05-21 12:39:12.259: W/System.err(17460):    at com.example.sunshine.MainActivity$GetWeatherDetails.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:118)
05-21 12:39:12.264: W/System.err(17460):    at com.example.sunshine.MainActivity$GetWeatherDetails.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-21 12:39:12.264: W/System.err(17460):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-21 12:39:12.264: W/System.err(17460):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-21 12:39:12.269: W/System.err(17460):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-21 12:39:12.279: W/System.err(17460):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-21 12:39:12.279: W/System.err(17460):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-21 12:39:12.279: W/System.err(17460):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weather` is direct child of `list`, so you should list to retrieve it,

```
 weatherList = c.getJSONArray(TAG_WEATHER);
```

should do it